# In .NET, How to execute this Oracle PL/SQL Procedure?

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

My procedure is declare here :

```
create or replace
PACKAGE MYPKG
IS
PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE(
        sNom            IN VARCHAR2,
        sValeur         OUT VARCHAR2,
        sCommentaire    OUT VARCHAR2,
        sRetour         OUT VARCHAR2,
        sMsgRetour      OUT VARCHAR2);
END;
```

The execution is Ok with SQL Developer.

I try to execute this procedure in C# :

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("MYPKG.MYPROCEDURE", OraCon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
OracleParameter name = new OracleParameter("sNom", OracleType.VarChar);
name.Value = "CG";
cmd.Parameters.Add(name);
OracleParameter valeur = new OracleParameter("sValeur", OracleType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add(valeur);
OracleParameter commentaire = new OracleParameter("sCommentaire", OracleType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add(commentaire);
OracleParameter retour = new OracleParameter("sRetour", OracleType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add(retour);
OracleParameter msgRetour = new OracleParameter("sMsgRetour", OracleType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add(msgRetour);

using (OracleDataReader row = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (row.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row.GetValue(0));
    }
}
```

I have the error "Wrong Parameter".
How execute the PL/SQL procedure ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would approach it.

NOTE: I have compiled this code, but I have not tested it against a database, although I have lots of similar code that works fine.

Also note: you are not getting back a collection, so you should really be using OraCmd.ExecuteNonQuery rather than OraCmd.ExecuteReader

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;


    namespace Testing
    {
        public class OracleCommandTest
        {

            string m_strConnectionsString = string.Empty;

            //Constructor
            public OracleCommandTest()
            {
                //Get the connection string from the app.config            
                m_strConnectionsString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;

                //if it is a web app, then use this call instead
                //m_strConnectionsString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;

            }



            public void getData(string sNom, out string sValeur, out string sCommentaire, out string sRetour, out string sMsgRetour)
            {
                OracleConnection ora_conn = new OracleConnection(m_strConnectionsString);

                try
                {
                    ora_conn.Open();

                    /*********************Oracle Command**********************************************************************/
                    OracleCommand ora_cmd = new OracleCommand("MYPKG.MYPROCEDURE", ora_conn);
                    ora_cmd.BindByName = true;
                    ora_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("sNom", OracleDbType.Varchar2, sNom, ParameterDirection.Input);
                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("sValeur", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("sCommentaire", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("sRetour", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
                    ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("sMsgRetour", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
                    /*********************Oracle Command**********************************************************************/

                    ora_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //Now get the values output by the stored procedure    
                    sValeur = ora_cmd.Parameters["sValeur"].Value.ToString();
                    sCommentaire = ora_cmd.Parameters["sCommentaire"].Value.ToString();
                    sRetour = ora_cmd.Parameters["sRetour"].Value.ToString();
                    sMsgRetour = ora_cmd.Parameters["sMsgRetour"].Value.ToString();




                }

                //catch (Exception ex)
                //{
                //    WebErrorHandling.WriteToEventLog("PRVEquipment_DAL.getPRVEquipment", ex);

                //}
                finally
                {
                    if (ora_conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        ora_conn.Close();
                    }
                }

            }


        }


    }
```

Hope this helps

Harvey Sather

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the `Direction` for the parameters.

You have to set `ParameterDirection.Output` since you are expecting values to be returned from the stored procedure else its by default considered as input parameter and so the error

Comment: Thank's, it's a part of the problem (cf the other discussion).

Answer (score 0):

Use `OracleType` enumeration for the parameters types. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracletype.aspx)
Also you should set the `Direction` of the parameters.
[Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/john_charles/CallingOraclestoredproceduresfromMicrosoftdotNET06222007142805PM/CallingOraclestoredproceduresfromMicrosoftdotNET.aspx)

Comment: I set the Direction.
Now the error is :

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1

But I set DbType.String, is not correct type ?

Comment: Same error when I replace DbType.String by OracleType.VarChar.

Comment: The last problems comes from i must set Size property to the OracleParameter.
Thanks for youor help.